# Newbie question about file formatting in Python

Tags: python, file, curl, pastebin

I'm writing a simple program in Python 2.7 using pycURL library to submit file contents to pastebin.
Here's the code of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import pycurl, os

def send(file):
    print "Sending file to pastebin...."
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://pastebin.com/api_public.php")
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, True)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, "paste_code=%s" % file)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.NOPROGRESS, True)
    curl.perform()

def main():
    content = raw_input("Provide the FULL path to the file: ")
    open = file(content, 'r')
    send(open.readlines())
    return 0

main()
```

The output pastebin looks like standard Python list: `['string\n', 'line of text\n', ...]` etc.

Is there any way I could format it so it looks better and it's actually human-readable? Also, I would be very happy if someone could tell me how to use multiple data inputs in `POSTFIELDS`. Pastebin API uses `paste_code` as its main data input, but it can use optional things like `paste_name` that sets the name of the upload or `paste_private` that sets it private.

Comment: I recommend asking the `POSTFIELDS` question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pycurl, os

def send(file_contents, name):
    print "Sending file to pastebin...."
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://pastebin.com/api_public.php")
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, True)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, "paste_code=%s&paste_name=%s" \
                                   % (file_contents, name))
    curl.setopt(pycurl.NOPROGRESS, True)
    curl.perform()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = raw_input("Provide the FULL path to the file: ")
    with open(content, 'r') as f:
        send(f.read(), "yournamehere")
    print
```

When reading files, use the `with` statement (this makes sure your file gets closed properly if something goes wrong).

There's no need to be having a `main` function and then calling it. Use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` construct to have your script run automagically when called (unless when importing this as a module).

For posting multiple values, you can manually build the url: just seperate different key, value pairs with an ampersand (`&`). Like this: `key1=value1&key2=value2`. Or you can build one with `urllib.urlencode` (as others suggested).

**EDIT**: using `urllib.urlencode` on strings which are to be posted makes sure content is encoded properly when your source string contains some funny / reserved / unusual characters.

Answer (score 3):

First, use `.read()` as `virhilo` said.

The other step is to use `urllib.urlencode()` to get a string:

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, urllib.urlencode({"paste_code": file}))
```

This will also allow you to post more fields:

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, urllib.urlencode({"paste_code": file, "paste_name": name}))
```

Answer (score 0):

use .read() instead of .readlines()

Comment: Please provide more of an explanation, what does one do than the other doesn't, why is one more helpful for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `POSTFIELDS` should be sended the same way as you send Query String arguments. So, in the first place, it's necessary to [encode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) the string that you're sending to `paste_code`, and then, using `&` you could add more POST arguments.

Example:

```
paste_code=hello%20world&paste_name=test
```

Good luck!